# randu in R: fill matrix without for loop

Tags: r

Take the following implementation of the **bad** pseudorandom number generator (PRNG) [randu](http://www.r-bloggers.com/randu-the-case-of-the-bad-rng/):

```
n = 100000
randu = matrix(NA, ncol=3, nrow=n)
new_z = 1

for(i in 1:n) {
    new_x = (65539*new_z) %% 2^31
    new_y = (65539*new_x) %% 2^31
    new_z = (65539*new_y) %% 2^31
    randu[i,] = c(x=new_x/2^31, y=new_y/2^31,z=new_z/2^31)
}
```

I want to replace the for loop. The problem here is that the entries of a whole row, which are generated with each iteration step, are needed for the subsequent iteration step. My idea is to apply a function to fill the rows of an empty matrix. So I am trying to become familiar with the `apply` function and I got this far:

```
n = 100000
randu = matrix(NA, ncol=3, nrow=n)
randu[1,3] <- 1 # seed
randu.fct <- function() {
  randu[,1] <- (65539 * randu[,3]) %% 2 ^ 31
  randu[,2] <- (65539 * randu[,1]) %% 2 ^ 31
  randu[,3] <- (65539 * randu[,2]) %% 2 ^ 31 
}
apply(randu[,1:3],1,randu.fct)
```

..which is not very much. I can't get my head around how to iterate over every element of a row and how to generate e.g. 100000 rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace (hide) the loop by `replicate`:

```
n = 100000
x = 1
matrix(replicate(3*n, {x <<- (65539*x) %% 2^31})/2^31, ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE)
```

If you need speed you should probably take a look at `Rcpp`, here follows a simple implementation:

```
library(inline)
library(Rcpp)

cppFunction(
    'NumericMatrix randU(int n) {
        NumericMatrix X(n, 3);
        int x = 1;
        unsigned int d = 2147483648;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
          for (int j = 0; j < 3; ++j) {
               x = (65539*x) % d;
               X(i,j) = x  / double(d);
          }
        }
        return X;
    }'
)

> all.equal(randu, randU(100000))
[1] TRUE
```

A small speed comparison:

```
f1 <- function(){
    n = 100000
    randu = matrix(NA, ncol=3, nrow=n)
    new_z = 1
    for(i in 1:n) {
        new_x = (65539*new_z) %% 2^31
        new_y = (65539*new_x) %% 2^31
        new_z = (65539*new_y) %% 2^31
        randu[i,] = c(x=new_x/2^31, y=new_y/2^31,z=new_z/2^31)
    }  
    randu
}

f2 <- function(){
    n = 100000
    x = 1
    matrix(replicate(3*n, {x <<- (65539*x) %% 2^31})/2^31, ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE)
}

f3 <- function(){
    randU(100000)
}


Unit: milliseconds
 expr         min          lq        mean      median          uq       max neval
 f1() 1170.166889 1245.987545 1331.918328 1320.593903 1356.121828 1593.0860    10
 f2() 1194.103998 1449.195295 1499.362126 1514.794140 1562.868296 1798.1218    10
 f3()    2.041235    2.055671    3.386515    2.207969    2.676895   13.1357    10
```

Comment: Thanks! I like the inline C++, that's really useful. I'm still interested in the functionality of the `apply` function, concerning such matrix operations, but I think I'll first check http://www.r-bloggers.com/?s=apply